# alignItems: 'flex-end' doesn't work properly (it doesb't cover the whole page) - react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

So in my homepage I have 4 buttons which I've laid out with flex. I've set the parent's flex: 1, which means it's covering the whole page (I've made sure of that with backgroundColor). My problem is that when I set alignItems: 'flex-end', the buttons only move down a little, as if the flex is covering only half the page.

Here's my code Mark-up:

```
<Card style={styles.cardStyle}>
      <CardSection style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Button onPress={() => navigate("NewScreen")}>
          New
        </Button>
      </CardSection>

      <CardSection style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Button onPress={() => navigate("SavedScreen")}>
          Saved
        </Button>
      </CardSection>

      <CardSection style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Button onPress={() => navigate("ParametersScreen")}>
          Settings
        </Button>
      </CardSection>

      <CardSection style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Button onPress={() => navigate("FMRScreen")}>
          FMR
        </Button>
      </CardSection>

    </Card>
```

Card Style:

```
cardStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#0000ff',
}
```

CardSection style:

```
containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginTop: 10,
},
```

And the style for the items:

```
textStyle: { 
    color: '#007aff',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '600',
},
buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor: '#007aff',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Note that this problem goes away if I remove flexWrap: 'wrap', but I can't do this!

Any ideas?

Comment: And the CSS for the flex items...? Also show us the markup

Comment: Okay, you need to set `alignItems` on `card`

Comment: @LGSon to the items or the parent?

Comment: @LGSon I've already done that, set it to 'center'

Comment: @Michael_B yes it was the same problem. thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @Michael_B Tried to close as dupe though I haven't enough reps. for the initial tags :) ... and when change myself, still won't allow to close singlehanded, and now, as we know it was the same issue, you can close it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this to make that work properly, where it is the `<Card>` element being the outer most flex parent of the flex items.

*Note the added `alignContent: 'flex-end'`, which is needed when flex items wrap*

```
<Card style={styles.containerStyle}>

  <CardSection style={styles.sectionStyle}>
    <Button onPress={() => navigate("NewScreen")}>
      New
    </Button>
  </CardSection>

  <CardSection style={styles.sectionStyle}>
    <Button onPress={() => navigate("SavedScreen")}>
      Saved
    </Button>
  </CardSection>

  <CardSection style={styles.sectionStyle}>
    <Button onPress={() => navigate("ParametersScreen")}>
      Settings
    </Button>
  </CardSection>

  <CardSection style={styles.sectionStyle}>
    <Button onPress={() => navigate("FMRScreen")}>
      FMR
    </Button>
  </CardSection>

</Card>

containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    alignContent: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: '#0000ff',
}

sectionStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginTop: 10,    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't this exactly my code?

Comment: @TheMonster No, you add the `containerStyle` to the `CardSection` and it should be on the `Card` ... made an update just now, check style variable names and where to apply in markup

Comment: I'd written them in different .js files, so they both had the same names. I've edited the question for better clarification. I'm doing exactly what you said in your answer, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheMonster After your update, do note you use `alignItems: 'center',` ...not `flex-end`

Comment: @TheMonster And add `alignContent: 'flex-end'`

Comment: yes I was just trying alignContent and it worked. thanks